# Telegram bot keyboard

Tags: laravel, telegram-bot

I create a telegram bot keaboard with laravel. There is a part of code.

```
$available_buttons =ReportToAbonent::select("report_id")
    ->join("telegram.reports", "report_to_abonent.report_id", "=", "reports.id")
    ->where("abonent_id", "=", $abonent[0]->id)
    ->where("active","=","1")
    ->get();

$keyboard = array();
foreach ($available_buttons as $value)
{
    $keyboard[] = array($value->report_id);
}

$reply_markup = \Telegram::replyKeyboardMarkup([
    'keyboard' => $keyboard,
    'resize_keyboard' => true,
    'one_time_keyboard' => false
]);
```

If I print

```
$keyboard`, its structure looks like if `$keyboard = [
            ['7', '8', '9'],
            ['4', '5', '6'],
            ['1', '2', '3'],
            ['0']
        ];
```

But in first case no keyboard in telegram client. In the second case it is present. What can I do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong format in inline keyboard, please check out [API reference](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup).

And you can refer to this sample request:

Contains only one button: (Parameters and Response)

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]

Contains 2x3 buttons:

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]

Comment: Hi, your screenshots look very large. Could you make them a little more neat?

Comment: @mymedia Okay, I added only one button instance

Answer (score 0):

This is Two examples of each keyboard:

**Normal Keboard:**

```
  const opts = {
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
      keyboard: [
        ['Normal'],
      ],
      resize_keyboard: true,
      one_time_keyboard: true,
    }),
  };
```

**Inline Keboard:**

```
  const inlineopts = {
    reply_markup: {
      inline_keyboard: [
        [{
          text: 'Yahoo',
          url: 'www.yahoo.com',
        }],
        [{
          text: 'Google',
          url: 'www.google.com',
        }],
      ],
    },
  };
```